# FileOutputStream sends 0 byte file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I am trying to allow a user to download a file (attachment) using Java to serve up the download. I have been partially successful. The file is read, and on the client side there is a prompt for a download. A file is saved successfully, but it has 0 bytes. Here is my server side code:

```
String stored = "/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/myapp/attachments/" + request.getParameter("stored");
String realname = request.getParameter("realname");

// Open the input and output streams
FileInputStream attachmentFis = new FileInputStream(stored);
FileOutputStream attachmentFos = new FileOutputStream(realname);

try {
    // Send the file
    byte[] attachmentBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while((count = attachmentFis.read(attachmentBuffer)) != -1) {
        attachmentFos.write(attachmentBuffer, 0, count);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Exception handling
} finally {
    // Close the streams
    attachmentFos.flush();
    attachmentFos.close();
    attachmentFis.close();
}
```

For context, this is in a servlet. The files have an obfuscated name, which is passed as "stored" here. The actual file name, the name the user will see, is "realname".

What do I need to do to get the actual file to arrive at the client end?

**EDIT**
Following suggestions in the comments, I changed the `write` to include the `0, count` parameters and put the close stuff in a `finally` block. However, I am still getting a 0 byte file when I attempt a download.

**EDIT 2**
Thanks to the logging suggestion from Dave the Dane, I discovered the file was being written locally. A bit of digging and I found I needed to use `response.getOutputStream().write` instead of a regular `FileOutputStream`. I have been successful in getting a file to download through this method. Thank you all for your helpful suggestions.

Comment: Genreally `close` is placed in a `finally` block. Also consider using `try`-with-resources

Comment: Have you tried to print the catched exception? Also as a side note, you could replace the `close() ` calls using a `with` statement which makes your code less prone to keep opened file-handles hanging (= resource-leak)

Comment: You probably want to replace `attachmentFos.write(attachmentBuffer)` with `attachmentFos.write(attachmentBuffer, 0, count)` in order to not write garbage to the file.

Comment: Also your writing code is incorrect. You are repeatedly writing the whole buffer which may only have been partially filled by the reading operation. Find out how many bytes were read and then write that exact same number out. As said, try-with-resources is your friend. Your problem with reading writing will also be solved by `InputStream.transferTo`

Comment: I think the main problem is that it’s writing the content to another file on the server rather than the servlet output stream.

Comment: It’s also important to avoid using non validated user input to construct file system paths, as this is a cause of security vulnerabilities https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal

Comment: If you are trying to send a file to a HTTP client from a servlet, then shouldn't you call method [getOutputStream](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletresponse#getOutputStream--) of the `HttpServletResponse` parameter in the `doGet` (or `doPost`) method of your servlet? If you are sending a text file, then you should probably call method `getWriter` (rather than `getOutputStream`).

Answer (score 1):

As others have observed, you'd be better off using **try-with-resources** & let that handle the closing.

Assuming you have some Logging Framework available, maybe the following would cast light on the matter...

```
try {
    LOG.info ("Requesting....");

    final String                   stored   = "/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/myapp/attachments/" + request.getParameter("stored");
    LOG.info ("stored.......: {}", stored);

    final String                   realname = request.getParameter("realname");
    LOG.info ("realname.....: {}", realname);

    final File fileStored   = new File(stored);
    LOG.info ("fileStored...: {}", fileStored  .getCanonicalPath());

    final File fileRealname = new File(realname);
    LOG.info ("fileRealname.: {}", fileRealname.getCanonicalPath());

    try(final InputStream  attachmentFis = new FileInputStream (fileStored);
        final OutputStream attachmentFos = new FileOutputStream(fileRealname))
    {
        final byte[] attachmentBuffer = new byte[64 * 1024];

        int    count;
        while((count = attachmentFis.read (attachmentBuffer)) != -1) {
            ;          attachmentFos.write(attachmentBuffer, 0, count);

            LOG.info ("Written......: {} bytes to {}", count, realname);
        }
        attachmentFos.flush(); // Probably done automatically in .close()
    }
    LOG.info ("Done.");
}
catch (final Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Problem!.....: {}", request, e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Logging pointed to the problem; the file was being saved locally and not transmitted. This led me to figure out I needed to use response.getOutputStream to send the content.

Answer (score 0):

If it won't reach the `finally` block, you should stop ignoring the `IOException` which is being thrown:

```
catch (IOException e) {

    // Exception handling
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I'd asssume that the `realname` is just missing an absolute path.

Comment: That is also my suspicion. The Logging I posted as a Solution would expose that.